# awk function with a number parameter for the column you want to print

Tags: shell, alias, function

I want to use my awk shortcut as a function, so that I can pass the column number which then prints me the output. My aliases are:

```
alias A="| awk '{print \$1}'
alias G="| grep -i'
```

Instad of typing:

```
ps -ef | grep mysql | awk 'print $2'
```

I want to be able to type this:

```
ps -ef G mysql A 2
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: For a completely different approach, try `pgrep -f mysql` (assuming `pgrep` is available).

Comment: nice tool thx!!

Comment: Indeed.  And for arbitrary fields, `ps -o <field> $(pgrep mysql)`.

Comment: or `ps h -o %p -C mysqld` if you want the PIDs of a particular named process (-C is exact match, not search pattern or regexp).  You can have multiple -C args, e.g. `ps h -o %p -C mysqld -C mysql` to get client and server processes.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it's possible.  Basically, aliases can't take arguments (`$1`), and functions can't do macro expansion (`|`).

The closest options I can think of:

in `bash` or `zsh`

```
C() { col=$1; shift; eval "awkcmd='{ print \$$col }'"; echo "$awkcmd"; "$@" | awk "$awkcmd"; }

C 2 ps -ef G mysql
```

in `zsh`

```
alias -g F="| tr -s '[[:space:]]' | cut -d ' ' -f"

ps -ef G mysql F 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting pipes into aliases is awkward.  Instead, create a shell function that you can pipe things to:

```
G () {
    grep -i "$@"
}

A () {
    awk -v col="$1" '{ print $col }'
}
```

Then,

```
ps -ef | G mysql | A 2
```

But this particular pipeline would, on a Linux system, be more or less the same as

```
pgrep mysql
```